# Kafka producer config: Why request.timeout.ms should be larger than replica.lag.time.max.ms

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

From Kafka doc https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html#producerconfigs , it says that:

> The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request. If the response is not received before the timeout elapses the client will resend the request if necessary or fail the request if retries are exhausted. **This should be larger than replica.lag.time.max.ms (a broker configuration) to reduce the possibility of message duplication due to unnecessary producer retries.**

Why a small request.timeout.ms may cause duplication? Could someone elaborate more on that?

And does this still hold true if the producer retries config is set to 0?

Comment: request.timeout.ms should be greater than replica.lag.time.max.ms, otherwise producer retry will re-send/duplicate message even replication is not yet completed in broker.

Answer (score 0):

if it's smaller than replica.lag.time.max.ms , then follower broker might persistent the msg successfully but producer req timed out, which will cause the duplication due to unnecessary producer retries

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).